# Refreshing a portlet from a portlet on a popup

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, portlet

I have a page with a portlet (portlet A) and a button to open a popup window. `Liferay.Util.openWindow( .. )`

On the popup window, I have another portlet (portlet B), I update few things on portlet B and I want to reload the portlet A after the updates are done.

I tried Liferay refresh command,   `Liferay.Portlet.refresh('#p_p_id_testjson_WAR_testjson_');`

But this applies when you are on the same page. In other words, it doesnt work from a popup window.

How to refresh a portlet from another portlet which is on a popup window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution can be, put refresh function call in javascript function X of testjson portlet. And from popup window, call that X function by `parent.X()` .

Comment: I am unaware of the parent thing... Can we have inheritance in portlets as well?